# How to reduce Execution time to check the existence of a list element in R?

Tags: r, list

I have few lists corresponding to several cell lines. Each list contains the expression values of around 5000 genes. For example

```
Gm12878 <- list('gene1'= 3.14, 'gene4' = 1.11, 'gene10'= 1111,...)
K562 <- list('gene4'= 8.1, 'gene20'= 0.11, 'gene31'= 100,...)
.
.
H1hESC <- list('gene1'= 5.1, 'gene31'= 1.11, 'gene200'= 10,...)
```

The name of the cell lines is contained inside another list named Cells. The structure of Cells is

```
Cells[1] <- "Gm12878"
Cells[2] <- "K562"
.
.
Cells[5] <- "H1hESC"
```

In another list I have the name of all genes. For example,

```
Genelist[1] <- "gene1"
Genelist[2] <- "gene2"
.
.
Genelist[15000] <- "gene150050"
```

I want to check whether a gene, i.e. an element of Genelist (e.g. "gene10500") exists in a Cell line list or not.

Here is my code:

```
Cells <- list("Gm12878","K562", "H1hESC")

for(i in 1:length(Genelist)){
  for(j in 1:length(Cells)){
    check_val <- eval(parse(text=paste(c(Cells[j],"$`", annotation_list[i],"`"), collapse = "")))
    if(is.null(check_val)){
      print("FALSE")
      } else {
        print(check_val)
      }
  }
  }
```

Unfortunately, the code is taking very long time to execute if the Genelist is very long (in my case it is around 155000). Any suggestions on how to reduce the execution time?

Comment: Is this sorted in any ways ?

Comment: None of these lists is in sorted/ordered. is there any way to search the list in O(1) time complexity as it possible in hash function? I think `the parse function` is taking long time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the names of the list:

```
Gm12878 <- list('gene1'= 3.14, 'gene4' = 1.11, 'gene10'= 1111)
K562 <- list('gene4'= 8.1, 'gene20'= 0.11, 'gene31'= 100)
H1hESC <- list('gene1'= 5.1, 'gene31'= 1.11, 'gene200'= 10)

Genelist <- c("gene1", "gene4", "gene50")
Cells <- list("Gm12878","K562", "H1hESC")

for(c in Cells) {
  print(eval(parse(text=paste0("Genelist %in% names(", c, ")"))))
}
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: is it possible to get the value where TRUE results are coming?

Comment: Sure, what do you want the name of the gene or the value in the Cells?

Answer (score 1):

It is probably better (as in faster run time and shorter code) if you organize your cell/gene dataset in a relational format as follows

```
Gm12878 <- list('gene1'= 3.14, 'gene4' = 1.11, 'gene10'= 1111)
K562 <- list('gene4'= 8.1, 'gene20'= 0.11, 'gene31'= 100)
H1hESC <- list('gene1'= 5.1, 'gene31'= 1.11, 'gene200'= 10)

Genelist <- c("gene1", "gene4", "gene50")
Cells <- c("Gm12878","K562", "H1hESC")

#reorganize into a relational format
library(data.table)
genes <- rbindlist(lapply(Cells, function(x) cbind(Cell=x, stack(get(x)))))
setkey(genes, Cell, ind)
genes
```

For simple query like checking if gene1 is in Gm12878:

```
genes[.("Gm12878", "gene1"), .N > 0]
#[1] TRUE
```

Or to see all in 1 big data.frame

```
dcast(genes, ind ~ Cell, function(x) length(x) > 0, value.var="ind")

       ind Gm12878  K562 H1hESC
1:   gene1    TRUE FALSE   TRUE
2:   gene4    TRUE  TRUE  FALSE
3:  gene10    TRUE FALSE  FALSE
4:  gene20   FALSE  TRUE  FALSE
5:  gene31   FALSE  TRUE   TRUE
6: gene200   FALSE FALSE   TRUE
```